# How to download HTML, CSS, and IMGs using Puppeteer and JSDOM

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, jsdom

I'm trying to use Puppeteer to download any given web page.
I would like to download the HTML file, the CSS sources, and all the images to a local folder (and so be able to read the pages later, without being connected to internet).

The problems are:

- 1- I haven't find how to parse the HTML file to detect CSS and images
  sources and how to download it.
- 2- I have not figured how to change these assets path and make sure
  it will point to my local folder.

So far, I'm not sure what is the best way to parse the "html" const content (see below). I haven't figured how to edit the html using JSDOM.

```
    const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
    const jsdom = require('jsdom');

    const { JSDOM } = jsdom;


    (async () => {
      const url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54507560/how-to-download-html-css-and-imgs-using-puppeteer';
      const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
      const page = await browser.newPage();
      await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: 'load'});
      const html = await page.content();

      const dom = new JSDOM(html);

      // I'm trying to grab all the img and so to be able to edit the path
      console.log(dom.window.document.querySelectorAll("img"));


      // ^ this is not working it return the following object in my node shell : 
      // NodeList { '0': HTMLImageElement {}, '1': HTMLImageElement {} } 
      // I don't know how to process this object and to grab each image path and then to dl it. I don't know how to edit each path to make it relative to my local folder.

      browser.close();
    })();
```

Update : I'm now trying to parse the HTML using JSDOM.

Comment: How does it "not seem possible to parse the html content"? Any reason you cannot simply use a module like `cheerio`, call `var $ = cheerio.load(html)`, and use jquery-like parsing from there? 
Be a bit more specific on how you haven't been able to parse the "html", including your attempt at doing so.

Comment: @MadWard usefull comment but isn't JSDOM a better way to do so? I just made a new attempt but I've no clue on how to process and manipulate the dom with this api.

Comment: Alright, posted an answer detailing how to 1) replace every <img src> url in the document, and 2) replace the URL of every resource that is an image. Both are working, tested snippets, you may use any of them if they suit your goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Op here. 
Here is a built in solution I found :
https://github.com/website-scraper/website-scraper-puppeteer
So here is the code as it is written on the repository. 
It seems to be working really well !

```
const scrape = require('website-scraper');
const PuppeteerPlugin = require('website-scraper-puppeteer');

scrape({
    urls: ['https://www.instagram.com/gopro/'],
    directory: '/path/to/save',
    plugins: [ new PuppeteerPlugin() ]
});
```

Answer (score 2):

**Changing all `<img src>` tags in the active page**

To change all the img tags in the document, you will need to run [`page.evaluate()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args) and use `document.querySelectorAll()` there, in the browser. Here is a quick working snippet that removes the domain from each image source in the document:

```
(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();

  const url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54507560/how-to-download-html-css-and-imgs-using-puppeteer';
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: 'load'});

  await page.evaluate(() => {
    var imgs = document.querySelectorAll('img');
    imgs.forEach(function(img){
      let imageSrc = img.getAttribute("src");
      img.setAttribute("src", imageSrc.replace(/^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:[^@\n]+@)?(?:www\.)?([^:\/\n?]+)/img, ""));
      console.log(img.getAttribute("src"));
    });
  });  
})();
```

---

**Changing the URL for each resource that is an image**

This is a bit more complicated. In short, you need to intercept every request made by the browser, and [`continue()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#requestcontinueoverrides) it with the modified URL.

Again, a working snippet that replaces every image resource URL with a domain of our choice:

```
var newDomain = "https://example.com";

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});

  const url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54507560/how-to-download-html-css-and-imgs-using-puppeteer';
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setRequestInterception(true);

  page.on('request', (interceptedRequest) => {
    // Continue if request URL is page URL
    if (interceptedRequest.url() == page.url()) {
      interceptedRequest.continue();
      return;
    }

    // Intercept if request resource is an Image
    if (interceptedRequest.resourceType() == "image") {
      // Replace target domain with the new domain we want
      let newUrl = interceptedRequest.url().replace(/^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:[^@\n]+@)?(?:www\.)?([^:\/\n?]+)/img, newDomain);
      console.log(newUrl);
      interceptedRequest.continue({
        url: newUrl,
      });
      return;
    }

    // Continue any other requests
    interceptedRequest.continue();
  })

  await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: 'load'});

})();
```

Comment: Thanks for this MadWard. 
I found a built-in solution which is doing exactly what I wanted